# How to pass a powershell variable defined in one stage of jenkinsfile to another stage of same jenkinsfile?

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the $project variable that I defined in stage build repo. When I output it in the same stage it is working fine but whenever I try to use it or output in next stage then it shows null value.

```
stage('Build repo') {
            agent {
                label 'test'
            }
            steps {


                   checkout scm     

                        powershell '''
                         $project= "proj"
                                     '''
  }
} 
stage('next stage') {
            agent {
                label 'test'
            }
            steps {


                   checkout scm     

                        powershell '''
                         $project //value is null
                                     '''
  }
}
```

value pro $project in step 2 should have outpu proj as well or how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    After some research and help from a firend I have finally figureout the solution.

        `stage('Build repo') {
                    agent {
                        label 'test'
                    }
                    steps {


                           checkout scm     

                                powershell '''
                                 $project= "proj"
        [environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("projectGlobal", $project, "Machine")

                                             '''
          }
        } 
        stage('next stage') {
                    agent {
                        label 'test'
                    }
                    steps {


                           checkout scm     

                                powershell '''
     $projectGlobal=[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("projectGlobal","Machine")
  "this variable contains: $projectGlobal" //outputs value here
           '''                                
          }
        } `
```

Comment: If the same pipeline job i am running with different params this environment variable is getting mess up. Do we have any other solution ?